# Are RESTEasy, JAX-RS just tools to develop RESTful web services?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web-applications

I'm learning about RESTful web services and there is a lot of terminology jumbled up in my head. Can someone briefly provide a distinction between the following technologies.

1. RESTEasy
2. JAX-RS & JAX-WS
3. Jersey
4. Restlet
5. JAXB

If I want to develop a RESTful web service and have that web service be consumed by an Android app, which technologies from the above should I use? I do not want to use SOAP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone briefly provide a distinction between the following
>   technologies?

**JAX-WS ([JSR-224](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224))**

This is the Java standard for SOAP web services which are different from RESTful web services.  There are multiple implementations of this standard.

**JAX-RS ([JSR-311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311))**

This is the Java standard for RESTful web services.  There are multiple implementations of this standard which include:

- Jersey (http://jersey.java.net)
- Restlet with JAX-RS Extension (http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.1/13-restlet/28-restlet/57-restlet.html)
- RESTEasy (https://www.jboss.org/resteasy/)

**JAXB ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222))**

This is the Java standard for converting objects to/from XML.  All JAX-RS implementations leverage a JAXB implementation when the JAX-RS service returns Java objects that need to be converted to/from XML.  Some even leverage it when converting to/from JSON.  There are multiple implementations of this standard.

- Project JAXB (http://jaxb.java.net)
- EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)

---

> If I want to develop a RESTful web service and have that web service
>   be consumed by an Android app, which technologies from the above
>   should I use?

Any Java EE 6 compliant application server will all the components necessary to create a RESTful web service that can easily be consumed by an Android app.  Below is a series of articles I wrote that should help:

- [Part 1 - The Database](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - JPA Entities](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - JAXB Bindings](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTFul Service](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The Client](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS are mainly used for web services but you can use it as servlet as you like.

I have used Jersey with Freemarker to develop frontend website and it works perfectly.

I have seen some projects which use Jersey as backend web services and backbone.js to develop frontend website.